# How to only zip the files of a specific user?

Tags: find, users, aix, zip

I like zip, it's simple, but recently I came with the need of only zipping the file owned by one user in a directory.

I read the manual and I can't find any option to for example do things like:

```
zip /tmp/file.zip -own antoine -r /usr/something/*
```

Does I miss the option or maybe it's possible with other archive standard format (I'm open to suggestion though I work on AIX and might miss some options or binary)

Comment: If the filenames and directory names do not have spaces you can use the output of `find -user antoine` as arguments to zip. `zip` unfortunately does not have an option to read NUL separated filenames, and so doesn't handle files with spaces and newlines in the name very well if provided from another command. Alternative is to write a python script, it has a good zip module and there special filenames are easily handled.

Comment: @anthon, I think that might feet my actual situation as no file get a space in there name

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can try to find the relevant files with `find`:

```
find /usr/something -maxdepth 1 -user antoine
```

You can then use `-exec` to create a zip file from the results of `find`:

```
find /usr/something -maxdepth 1 -user antoine -exec zip /tmp/file.zip {} +
```

leave out the maxdepth if you want to recurse.

Comment: `-own` ? :D are you sure

Comment: @Kiwy trying to do two things at a time, updated

Comment: well thanks it work but I will wait if anybody came with the `posixy` miraculous solution out of nowhere before accepting the answer :-)

Comment: @Kiwy afaik there is no POSIX complyant Python :p

Comment: @Kiwy, There's no POSIX `zip`. The POSIX equivalent of `-maxdepth 1` is `\( -name . -o -prune \)` though here chances are you  want `-mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1`, that is `! -name . -prune`.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas I mention in the question that I was open to other format or archive if available

Comment: @jordanm why have you changethe answer from `zip  /tmp/file.zip $(find /usr/something -maxdepth 1 -user antoine)` to `find /usr/something -maxdepth 1 -user antoine -exec zip /tmp/file.zip {} +`

Comment: @kiwy because they both accomplish the same thing but the changed version handles files that contain spaces.

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`:

```
zip mine.zip ./*(.U)
```

to zip my (regular) files.

```
zip antoine.zip ./*(.u:antoine:)
```

to zip antoine's

Comment: If you don't use `zsh`, but you happen to have it installed (OS X provides a copy), you can use `zsh -c 'zip ...'`.

Comment: no luck no zsh installed at all, thought the solution is very nice, i should take a look at this zsh thingy

Answer (score 6):

Using only features available on AIX or other POSIX-and-hardly-more systems:

```
find /usr/something/* /usr/something/.[!.]* /usr/something/..?* \
     -prune -type f -user antoine -exec zip -r /tmp/file.zip {} +
```

`find` recurses into subdirectories. To avoid that, `-prune` tells it to not descend into the directories it encounters. That's no good if I run `find /usr/something -type d -prune -o …` because then `/usr/something` would be skipped. So I run `find` on all the entries in that directory, except `.` and `..`.

An easier idiom is to switch to the directory and treat the starting directory `.` specially. Here, it would change the resulting archive, which would have paths of the form `./foo` instead of `usr/something/foo`. This technique relies on the fact that `-name .` only matches the starting directory, every other encountered file will have its own name.

```
cd /usr/something &&
find . ! -name . -prune -type f -user antoine -exec …
```

Note that `zip` may be executed more than once if the list of file names is too long for a single invocation. This is ok because `zip -r` replaces existing files in the archive; if you use another archiver, take care not to invoke it in a mode where it would create a new archive (e.g. don't use `tar -c`).

Comment: You can do `find /usr/something/. ! -name . -prune ...` you don't need to `cd` into it or pass the whole file list to `find` using shell wildcards.

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
find /usr/something -maxdepth 1 -user antoine | zip /tmp/file.zip -@
```